# Property 'tableData' does not exist on type 'IPerson' in MaterialTable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, material-table

I have a MaterialTable component and I added the `editable` attribute to it. For `onRowUpdate` and `onRowDelete` methods, I want to get the index of the updated or removed item.

This is the minimal reproducible sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-fast-z84qq?file=/src/App.tsx

I got the error when I obtained the index of the item. Should I include the `tableData` property to my `IPerson` interface? How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I include the tableData property to my IPerson interface?

No, because you will probably use your `IPerson` interface throughout your application, and adding a `tableData` property that may or may not exist (see below) will defeat the purpose of typechecking. Typescript is telling you that `tableData` doesn't exist on your `IPerson` interface, which is correct. However, the underlying Javascript from your dependency has appended your object with a `tableData` property for its own internal purposes (and external if this is the only way to get at the index) and didn't bother to let Typescript know. Your code runs, the index is available for use.

There are probably better ways to do this, but you could create an `IPersonAfterRowUpdate` interface that has the tableData object on it:

```
interface IPersonAfterRowUpdate extends IPerson {
  tableData: { id: number };
}

/* ... */

onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
            new Promise<void>((resolve, _reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                if (oldData) {
                  const updatedData = [...data];
                  const index = (oldData as IPersonAfterRowUpdate).tableData.id;
                  updatedData[index] = newData;
                  setData(updatedData);
                  resolve();
                }
                _reject(new Error('Could not find oldData'));
              }, 1000);
            }),
```

Notice we have to check that `oldData` exists otherwise TS wouldn't like us indexing `updatedData` with a possible `undefined` value.

Then submit a PR to this library with this function typed correctly!